# Embed KML / KMZ file in Drupal 7

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7, kml, google-earth, kmz

I'm currently doing the Drupal website and I have to add "KML" file in my site. So, I add the following codes.

```
function Map() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('coverageMap'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 16.800925763233845, lng: 96.1567211151123}
   });

   var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://test.dev/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/coverage/coverage_map.kmz');
   kmzLayer.setMap(map);

}
```

When I run this code, I did not see the coverage area of what I did. It just shows like the google map. But, when I open that file in google earth, it shows coverage area by highlighting the color.

So, I think that happens because I add "kmz" file not "kml" file.
I'm not expert at that . So, can anyone help me how to add that file and implement in Drupal 7 ? 
I would like to show  the map (may be google map style) but it must show coverage area of highlighting with the color.

Comment: What is the size of your KML? Be aware that Maps JavaScript API has certain restrictions regarding KML files: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#restrictions

Comment: Also, looks like your URL `http://test.dev/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_business/coverage/coverage_map.kmz` is not publicly accessible. Google can render only publicly accessible KMLs.

Comment: @xomena , Yes bro. I put the kmz file inside drupal folder. Can't I put it in offline folder? I've never been do that kml file before bro. Could you please help me how should I do this ?